# Hypothesis testing simple null vs. complex alternative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

This is a simple hypotheses testing question between a simple null and a complex alternative.
I want to test the null hypothesis $H_0 : \mu = \mu_0$ against the alternative $H_1 : \mu = \mu_0 \pm \epsilon =\mu_1$  where $\epsilon$ is a fixed number where $\mu_0+\epsilon$ and $\mu_0-\epsilon$ are both equally likely. So can I say that the most powerful test is the one where we test for $\mu_0>\mu_1$ and $\mu_0<\mu_1$?